# Scraping XML with Python module BeautifulSoup, need a specific tag in the tree

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

So I've been working on this python script for a while and I'm trying to scrape the Duration and Distance tags under the Leg tag. The problem is that in the Step tag, there is also a sub tag called Duration and Distance and the Step tag is a sub tag of the Leg tag. When I scrape the data it returns those Distance and Duration tags as well. The XML is as follows:

```
<DirectionsResponse>
        <route>
           <leg>
            <step>...</step>
            <step>
                <start_location>
                <lat>38.9096855</lat>
                <lng>-77.0435397</lng>
                </start_location>
                <duration>
                <text>1 min</text>
                </duration>
                <distance>
                <text>39 ft</text>
                </distance>
            </step>
            <duration>
            <text>2 hours 19 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
            <text>7.1 mi</text>
            </distance>
              </leg>
        </route>
</DirectionsResponse>
```

Here is the Python script I'm using:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.somexmlgenerator.com/directions/xml?somejscript'
res = urllib.urlopen(url)
html = res.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.prettify()
leg = soup.findAll('leg')

for eachleg in leg:
    another_duration = eachleg('duration')
    print eachleg
```

As I mentioned I've been at this a while and have tried using lxml as well but I'm having difficultly scraping the XML through it since the XML is dynamically generated. I've taken the approach of instead scraping the XML as HTML but I'm definitely open to other suggestions as I am still quite a novice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With BeautifulSoup (use version 4, called `bs4`), you need to pass `recursive=False` into `findAll` to stop it from picking up the wrong durations:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(..., 'xml')

for leg in soup.route.find_all('leg', recursive=False):
    duration = leg.duration.text.strip()
    distance = leg.distance.text.strip()
```

Or with CSS:

```
for leg in soup.select('route > leg'):
    duration = leg.duration.text.strip()
    distance = leg.distance.text.strip()
```

With lxml, you just use XPath:

```
durations = root.xpath('/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/duration/text/text()')
distances = root.xpath('/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/distance/text/text()')
```

Comment: This may be a novice question, but I've installed BS4 on python version 2.7.3, I also have beautifulsoup3 installed so I wonder if thats the reason I cant call BS4 since it doesn't have a beautifulsoup file since thats in BS3?

Comment: @Logan: They're completely separate packages, so you can have both installed.